# Typescript setup in VisualStudio 2015 giving error: `exports is not defined`. How to correctly setup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I just started with typescript, I am going through export import in typescript

but when I started I am getting an error on exports,

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

and the error is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

after some google I go through [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999062)

but as per that answer my project should contain `tsconfig.json, common.js`

but I don't have any of these

here is screenshot of my project

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: Please don't pose pictures of your [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your scripts have to be precompiled using webpack or the like.  Is this the TypeScript HTML template from Visual Studio? Or how did you start this project?

Comment: Please ref [How to setup TypeScript environment in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397814/how-to-setup-typescript-environment-in-visual-studio-2015). Add tsconfig.json at the root of the web form project manually

Comment: @ChrisG I downloaded typescript for visual studio 2015 from microsoft website

Comment: @Rainmaker ok I will look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports`, or the shorter version `exports` is an object that only exists in Node.js

Trying to use the variable in the browser will give you  an `Uncaught reference error: exports is not defined`.

[Node.js documentation reference for the `exports` shortcut](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut)

You should add a `tsconfig.json` to your project, in which you set `module` to `es6` for example.

Your settings probably default to "commonjs", which expects you to have an `exports` object, which you do not have in the browser. Take a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685) for some additional reading.

Comment: so I had to add nodeJS in my current project?

Comment: Add a `tsconfig.json` to your project, in which you set `module` to `es6` for example. Your settings default to "commonjs", which expects you to have an `exports` object, which you do not have in the browser. Take a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685)